# Reordering Qt Listview via drag'n'drop

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have tried the approach described in http://agateau.com/2016/reordering-a-listview-via-dragndrop-3/ to implement drag'n'drop support in a listview.
However, when the amount of items in the list grow there is a problem when scrolling while dragging.

To reproduce the problem, download project from  https://github.com/agateau/listviewdragitem/tree/3-placeholders. Triple the amount of items in the list, and try to drag an item (all but first) to the end of the list. The dragged tem will dissapear when the list has scrolled for some time. I have not noticed any signals beeing emitted indicating that the drag has completed.

The first item can be moved correctly for some reason.

Do you have any suggestions what may cause this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason, that the first `Item` does not disappear is, that it is the `currentItem` which is protected from deletion.

The reason that the other `Item`s suddenly disappear is, that the `ListView` instantiates and destroyes the `Item`s as it thinks they are visible. This means: As they would be visible on their original position.

Set the `currentIndex` to the index of the `Item` that is being dragged, to prevent it from being destroyed.

Also you could use a `DelegateModel` and add relevant `Item`s to the persistent group, to prevent destruction.